# RichTextBox Control not rendering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtext

In my C# WinForms app the RichTextBox Control is not  rendering the RTF text.

The ListBullets are still present when I add a list and save the content.

It seems that FontStyles are reset to default, color,size, FontName ect.

So I assume it might be something wrong with the way Im setting a font.

`rtf.SelectionFont = new Font(rtf.SelectionFont.FontFamily, rtf.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);`

When I have the following and only make the title bold like so;

```
Hello World

* List item 1
* List Item 2
```

When I reload the RTF Text the bullets are still there but the font are reset to default.

**UPDATE**

OK what I found was if I set the Rtf property AFTER the control loads then all is good, but if I set the Rtf property before the control has loaded on screen I get these issues.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<Text></Text>` tags (which were probably added during the serialization process?

Comment: This works: `richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\b\i\f0\fs48 Hello World\b0\i0\fs20\par}";`

Comment: Yes the <Text> does not get put into the Rtf property. I was just showing that the Rtf was stored in an Xml doc.

Comment: @L.B - Then Im stumped at why the richtext control is not rendering my RTF

Comment: if you post a small but full repro it'd be easier to see what's stumping you here

Comment: I just did another test, with a basic RTF Control. Same problem. ListStyles are kept just font style, Font size are removed.

Comment: As requested by NSGaga, you have to include a code we might reproduce to understand the problem exactly. Everything matters here: the text you are adding (how you are adding it) and the selection definition (start and length).

Comment: @IEnumerable More to the point, why do you want to make selection changes and then reload the rtf? Do you mean that you save the changes and then reload? By 'reload' do you mean refresh the browser or get the text from some db?

Comment: This question is pretty unclear and confusing as to what the issue is.

Comment: As said already, Post [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If would be better if you showed us some more code.

If you are loading RTF document into a RichTextBox then you would do

```
richTextBox.Rtf = rtfString;
```

if it's plain text

```
richTextBox.Text = textString;
```